# Spring @EnableCaching with @Inject/@Autowired issue

Tags: spring, caching, autowired, inject

I found an issue when using @EnableCaching annotation together with @Inject/@Autowired in @Configuration class:

Simple example to reproduce:

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(){
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("books")));
        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Configuration
    static class DevProfileConfig {
        @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            EmbeddedDatabaseFactory factory = new EmbeddedDatabaseFactory();
            factory.setDatabaseType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL);
            return factory.getDatabase();
        }
    }
}
```

Application context launcher:

```
public class CacheConfigLauncher {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ApplicationContext springAppContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(CacheConfig.class);
    }
}
```

Error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Factory method [public org.springframework.cache.CacheManager
>   spring.samples.config.CacheConfig.cacheManager()] threw exception;
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object of
>   class [null] must be an instance of interface
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:573)
>     ... 76 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object of class [null]
>   must be an instance of interface
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory  at
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:339)     at
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:319)     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.getBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:414)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:289)
>     at
>   spring.samples.config.CacheConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f6ceccea.cacheManager()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
>     ... 77 more

However if you comment out either @Inject'ed field or @EnableCaching annotation configuration will be bootstraped without errors!!!

It seams like a bug for me. Have someone faced the same issue or probably I'm missing smth?

Thank you,

Oleg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue has been fixed in Spring v4.0.0.M2!**